# Is a mortgage-backed security something retail investors can buy?

Tags: real-estate, bonds, securities, mortgage-backed-securities

1. Is a mortgage-backed security (MBS) something retail investors can buy?
2. If so, what can make MBS a bad investment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is a mortgage-backed security (MBS) something retail investors can buy?

Technically, yes, but they are designed to be sold to institutional investors in bulk (i.e. in increments of tens of thousands of dollars). You probably can't buy, say, $500 of an MBS. If you want *exposure* to the MBS market you can look at ETFs that invest in MBSs. Plus, there are thousands of MBSs out there covering millions of mortgages - how will you know which one to buy?

> what can make MBS a bad investment?

The main risk of an MBS is prepayment/extension risk - meaning the risk that people pay more or less on their mortgages than expected. Both can be "bad" for different reasons. High prepayment can be bad because then investors get their principal back too soon, meaning they don't get as much "interest" passed through. This usually happens in a low interest-rate environment, so reinvestment must be done at lower rates. Extension risk is the opposite - the risk that people pay less on their mortgage than expected (*some* prepayment is always modeled in to an MBS, so it doesn't mean that they default, just that they don't overpay as much).

Answer (score 5):

In the US, retail investors can buy mortgage-backed securities issued by Ginnie Mae, Fannie Mae, Freddie Mac, and other private issuers. These securities trade over-the-counter, so you will need to find a dealer to ask for quotes. Not all stock brokerage firms deal in MBS. The minimum investment is usually $10,000 to $25,000.

FINRA has a good basic article about [Mortgage-Backed Securities](https://www.finra.org/investors/learn-to-invest/types-investments/bonds/types-of-bonds/mortgage-backed-securities). SIFMA also has a good fact sheet that explains how MBS work: [MBS Fact Sheet](https://www.sifma.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/MBS_FactSheet.pdf).

Comment: An explanation of MBS would increase the value of this answer, as the meat of it is really kept on 3rd party links at the moment.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Unfortunately, I am not knowledgeable enough to explain MBS. I just happen to know that they are available to retail investors through some dealers. That's why I only answered half of the question.